# "Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel' not found" Problem

Tags: laravel-5.7

[image]

I tried to upload a csv file, but while I tried it, there shows that "Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel' not found". How can I solve this?

Comment: Please Show me your `config/app.php` code

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a `composer dumpautoload;composer install`?